# Subtraction, Multiplication and Division script not working properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this code, which is a part of a calculator I am currently making.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a = "6-3";/*This is supposed to be entered in a textbox by a user*/

        int b = a.IndexOf(("-"));

        string c = a.Substring(0, b);

        int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(c);

        int b2 = a.IndexOf(("-"));
        string c2 = a.Substring(b);
        int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(c2);
        if(a.Contains("-"))
        {
            int an = num1 - num2;
            string ans = Convert.ToString(an);
            Console.WriteLine(ans);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this results in 9 instead of 3, which it is supposed to output. And if i try the exact same code with division or multiplication the program crashes. Strange as it may seem, the code works perfectly with addition. Any help?

Comment: Use a debugger, you'll find `num2` is *not* what you think it is. It's correctly subtracting `num1` and `num2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this line:

```
 string c2 = a.Substring(b);
```

`c2` is equal to "-3" and so converts to `-3`. `6 - -3` is 9.

Change the line to this:

```
 string c2 = a.Substring(b + 1);
```

There are numerous other problems, the code needs serious refactoring but that's off topic a little.

Comment: Thank you! That fixes the problems!

Answer (score 1):

When you substring `c2`, `b` is `1`. `"6-3".Substring(1)` will return -3.
 The substring parameters first input is how far forward to move. You need to move the index + 1 to move past the operator.

This makes your math problem `6 - - 3`

Comment: Thank you too for the help!

Answer (score 0):

that's because you make a substring of `-3`, not `3`. `string c2 = a.Substring(b);` should be `string c2 = a.Substring(b+1);`

a shorter version of this would be:

```
if(a.Contains("-")) 
{
    string[] nums = a.split('-')
    Console.WriteLine( ((int)nums[0]) - ((int)nums[1]) )
}
```

Comment: This would work but, as I mentioned in my code, I actually work with textboxes so converting back to string is essential I suppose.